# There's a way for edit a .ini file inside a .exe file? (I only want edit a "password=0" to "password=1")

Tags: windows, file-format

I lost my bios password so, I want update the bios using a .exe file from my laptop manufacturer and change one line inside the file platform.ini inside the .exe ( the line is  "password=0" to "password=1"), this should solve my problem, but I don't know how edit this without extract the .exe file and if I extract the program show me a erro:"file no found". Therefore if a I can edit the .ini while it's inside the .exe or reverse the extract...

Comment: Look in the manual, there is a method to reset the bios setting (generally with a jump on the mainboard)

Comment: I found the jump,but didn't work